# Hystrix Dashboard displays Loading

Tags: java, spring-boot, microservices, hystrix, hystrix-dashboard

I am using Hystrix and Hystrix Dashboard to view errors. While the hystrix stream works file, the Hystrix dashboard shows the "Loading..." msg and does not display failures or charts.

**Annotations used in GatewayServer**

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableEurekaClient
@EnableHystrix
```

**Hystrix entries in application.properties for GatewayServer**

```
management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=hystrix.stream
hystrix.command.fallbackcmd.execution.isolation.thread.timeoutInMilliseconds=5000
```

**Details of POM.XML for GatewayServer**

```
<groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
<version>2.5.10-SNAPSHOT</version>

<properties>
    <java.version>11</java.version>
    <spring-cloud.version>2020.0.5</spring-cloud.version>
</properties>


<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-gateway</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-circuitbreaker-reactor-resilience4j</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-hystrix</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.10.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

**Annotation used for Hystrix Dashboard**

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableHystrixDashboard
@EnableHystrix
```

**Hystrix entries in application.properties for Hystrix Dashboard**

```
management.endpoints.web.base-path=/
management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=*
hystrix.dashboard.proxy-stream-allow-list=*
```

**Details of POM.XML for GatewayServer**

```
<groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
<version>2.5.10-SNAPSHOT</version>

<properties>
    <java.version>11</java.version>
    <spring-cloud.version>2020.0.5</spring-cloud.version>
</properties>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-hystrix</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.10.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-hystrix-dashboard</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
</dependency>
```